# Comparing elements in different lists python

Tags: python, list, compare

I have four elements to compare with

```
A= [1,2,3,4]
B=[1,2]
C= [3,5,6]
D= [2, 4, 5, 6,7]
```

How do I compare which one has the greatest len?

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`max`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) with a key.

```
max(a,b,c,d,key=len)
```

Comment: I like this one line solution! neat! Well it is python after all

Comment: I always forget about the `key` keywords.  I really need to start making better use of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the len function, e.g.

```
len(A)
```

gives

```
4
```

So it would be something like:

```
len_a = len(A)
len_b = len(B)
len_c = len(C)
len_d = len(D)

max_length = max([len_a, len_b, len_c, len_d])

if len_a == max_length:
    print 'A'
if len_b == max_length:
    print 'B'
if len_c == max_length:
    print 'C'
if len_c == max_length:
    print 'D'
```

Comment: what if A and B have the same length?

Comment: @user2626540: edited ... now it gives multiple items if they have the same length.